# phonegap-facebook-plugin: only works when native FB app is not installed (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using this plugin to have a facebook-login option in my Phonegap app: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.

I've followed all the steps in the Android 'getting started' and everything works fine when I run the app on a device (emulator and real) that doesn't have the official Facebook app installed. When I run it on a device which has the official Facebook app installed and I click on the login button, the Facebook dialogue appears and it asks for permission. I choose OK, the dialogue disappears and nothing happens. No error or other alert appears and I'm not logged in neither.

How can I fix this?

The javascript:

```
function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
              alert('logged out');
              });
}


function logIn() {

     try {
          FB.init({ appId: "*****************", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });

          } catch (e) 
          {
          alert("error");
          }

    FB.login(
             function(response) {
             if (response.authResponse) { 

              // not invoked
              alert('logged in');      


             } else {
              // not invoked
             alert('error');
             }
             },
             { scope: "email" }
             );

}
```

Comment: Have you generated the key hash and added in your FB app settings?

Comment: @user thanks. I had already added it, but I had a typo. Now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for giving me the hint that it has something to do with the FB app setttings: in my case, the reason for this problem (phonegap-facebook-plugin: only works when native FB app is not installed (Android)) was, that I did not release-sign the Android app, that was using the phonegap-facebook-plugin.

After I signed my Android App in release mode (with the keystore that was used to generate the key hash), the app worked even with the FB App installed.

A side note: thank you to all the contributors on stackoverflow!! Without those tips & tricks & hints like this one, I would never be able to do my work.

Comment: im facing same problem. how did you sign it in release mode?

Comment: @itamar:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

Comment: I have the same same problem on iOS